# App Sandbox related

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing apps (for MAC) which will NOT be hosted on the app store.These apps will be installed by dmg file. Can someone please confirm my assumptions?

1. Even if I dont sandbox the apps, app will still work on OSX 10.7 and above (provided see point 2 below)
2. If the security setting is "Mac Appstore and identified developer", in a non sandboxed scenario, user needs to right click and open the dmg file instead of double click it and installer can install apps to Application folder. Once installed applications can - 
   -Interact each other
   -Access files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, out of the app store apps don't have to run in sandbox.
2. The security setting has nothing to do with how your app is installed. If you build a installer (Xcode can do it for you) or you if you send the .app bundle in a dmg to be dragged into applications folder is a thing of your choice. An app that is not running in sandbox can interact with any other app and with any system resource, only limit is user permissions. OS X is still Unix and the fact that app store has rules about sandbox doesn't change the world out of app store.